# Having issues with my search function in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, search

I'm trying to create a search function to go through my Contacts table and return any values that a like the search input but I'm not getting data back from the search. I've looked up many different solutions on slack and youtube, etc but I haven't been able to get it working...

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/search', 'ContactController@search')->name('contacts.search');
// Route::post('postSearch', ['as' => 'search', 'contacts' => 'contactsController@postSearch'])->name('contacts.postSearch');
Route::get('/postSearch', 'ContactController@postSearch')->name('contacts.postSearch');
// Route::get('/search/results/{query}{contact}','ContactController@postSearch')->name('contacts.postSearch');
```

**search.blade.php (in the contacts folder)***

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
                {{ Form::open(['route'=>'contacts.postSearch', 'method'=>'GET']) }}
                @include('contacts.form_search')
                {{ form::close() }}
        </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

***search form**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                <form action=" {{ route('contacts.postSearch') }} " method="get" class="form-inline">
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="search" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="search contacts">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </div>
                </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

**contact controller**

```
    public function search() 
    {
        return view('contacts.search');   
    }

    public function postSearch(Request $request)
    {
        // dump($request->toArray());
        $query = $request->get('search');
        dump($query);
        $contacts = DB::table('contacts')
            ->where('firstName', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->orWhere('lastName', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->orWhere('phone', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $query . '%');
        //     // ->orderBy();
        dump($contacts);
        // return $contacts;
        return view('contacts.postSearch', ['contacts' => $contacts]);
    }
```

***postSearch.blade.php in contacts folder***

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <h2>Search Results</h2>
    </div>
</div>
@if(isset($contacts))
<table class="table table-hover table-sm" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <tr>
        <th width = "100px">First Name</a></th>
        <th width = "100px">Last Name <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
        <th width = "100px">Email <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
        <th width = "100px">Phone <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
        <th width = "100px">Birthday <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
        <th width = "180px">Action <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
    </tr>

@foreach ($contacts as $key => $value)
    <tr>
                {{--  Need to add in sort functions for each catagory --}}
        <td>{{$value->firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->email}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->phone}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->birthday}}</td>
        <td>
            <form action="{{ route('contacts.destroy', $value->id) }}" method="post">
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="{{ route('contacts.show', $value->id)}}">Show</a>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" href="{{ route('contacts.edit', $value->id)}}">Edit</a>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-second" href="{{ route('contacts.createAddress', ['contact_id' => $value->id])}}">Add Address</a>
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach 
    </table>
    @endif
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order you get the actual data you need to do following:

```
public function postSearch(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->get('search');
    $contacts = DB::table('contacts')
        ->where('firstName', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
        ->orWhere('lastName', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
        ->orWhere('phone', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
        ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $query . '%');
        ->get();
```

The `->get()` method is going to return the data.

Comment: @CasaCoding Awesome! Please accept the answer if it helped you :)